# Where is the ActionType for AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am creating an **AWS CodePipeline** via **Terraform** but I am stuck at the **Deployment Stage**.
I would like to deploy my application to the **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**, but I cannot find the correct `ActionType` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference.html).

What is the `provider` and the configuration parameters needed for a Beanstalk deployment?

```
stage {
    name = "Deploy"

    action {
      category         = "Deploy"
      name             = "Deploy"
      output_artifacts = []
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = var.deploy_provider
      run_order        = 1
      version          = "1"

      configuration = {}
}
```

I am sure there is one, because I can manually configure it via web:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about terraform, but for Cloudformation, it should be:

```
Provider: "ElasticBeanstalk"
Configuration:
  ApplicationName: !Ref ApplicationName
  EnvironmentName: !Ref EnvironmentName
```

Try "ElasticBeanstalk" for provider and add ApplicationName and EnvironmentName keys in configuration.

Comment: Great! Thank you